# CSS - Create space between label and checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create space between label and checkbox. If I use class `.Test` then it is creating big gap between label and checkbox for all the item. But I would like to leave the first item as it is but to create space in 2nd and 3rd labels. I tried `label>#test1Label` but it did not work. I also tried `#test1Label`, still not worked.

JavaScript

```
$(".Test").parent().css({"width":"160px","height":"25px"});
 
 $("label>#test1Label").css({"width":"550px","height":"25px"});
 
 $("label>#test2Label").css({"width":"550px","height":"25px"});
```

HTML

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="" style="width: 160px; height: 25px;">
<span class="Test">
<label for="Test1" id="Test1Label" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 3px; padding: 2px;">Testing &nbsp; </label>
</span>
</td>
<td align="left" width="100%" id="TD1">
<input class="pro" type="CHECKBOX" name="ob" value="Ind" id="pro" onclick="" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td nowrap="" style="width: 160px; height: 25px;">
<span class="Test">
<label for="Test2" id="Test2Label" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 3px; padding: 2px;">Please select Testing 1 &nbsp; </label>
</span>
</td>
<td align="left" width="100%" id="TD1">
<input class="pro" type="CHECKBOX" name="ob" value="Ind1" id="pro" onclick="" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td nowrap="" style="width: 160px; height: 25px;">
<span class="Test">
<label for="Test3" id="Test3Label" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 3px; padding: 2px;">Please select Testing 2 from  &nbsp; </label>
</span>
</td>
<td align="left" width="100%" id="TD1">
<input class="pro" type="CHECKBOX" name="ob" value="Ind2" id="pro" onclick="" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use CSS instead?

Comment: @NickVu -  there is old legacy code. I am just trying to add my part into it.

Comment: You cannot modify HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new `<td>` element with a div inside in between the the input and the label something like this :

```
<td nowrap="" style="width: 160px; height: 25px;">
  <span class="Test">
    <label for="Test2" id="Test2Label" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 
    204, 204); border-radius: 3px; padding: 2px;">Please select Testing 1 
    &nbsp; </label>
  </span>
<td>
  <div class="label-space"></div>
</td>
<td align="left" width="100%" id="TD1">
  <input class="pro" type="CHECKBOX" name="ob" value="Ind1" id="pro" 
  onclick="" autocomplete="off">
</td>
```

Then add width to the div through css:

```
$(".label-space").css({"width":"15px"})
```

Comment: No I can't use different class name. But can't we use the label id for this?

Comment: Yes you can also use that instead. Something like this: $("#Test2Label, #Test3Label").css({"margin-left":"15px"})

Comment: But I would like to create space between label and checkbox so your solution doesn't work for that. Your css is moving the whole label to right.

Comment: I updated my answer to a new solution.